# "Such" as a part of speech, and similar words

Tags: nouns, adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech, determiners

The word "such" seems to fit under a few different categories. It could be arguably classified as:

- A noun - "The movie would only be of interest to *such* as enjoy mindless explosions every 45 seconds"
- An adjective - "After years of enduring the complaints of entitled customers, he was sick of dealing with *such* idiots"
- A pronoun - "If you retained a receipt, please enclose a copy of *such*"
- An adverb - "She wears *such* stylish clothes"

But it doesn't seem to be a "typical" noun/verb/adjective/adverb. For instance, in the sentence, "How could I be *such* an idiot?", it seems to be an adjective (modifying "an idiot") but can neither be placed directly in front of the noun it modifies ("How could I be a such idiot?"--compare the adjectives in "I'm a big fat idiot") nor intensified/modified directly with adverbs ("How could I be super such an idiot?" vs, again, "I'm a super big fat idiot"). I've heard of it being described as a "[*determiner*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner)," but that seems to be a completely different category that cuts across/includes words from all the "parts of speech" before mentioned (as well as some other ones, like articles), rather than a separate "part of speech" in its own right.

**Is there a canonical classification of "such" as a part of speech? And, are there other common English words that also don't fit neatly into the basic *Schoolhouse Rock* categories of "adverb/adjective/noun/verb/conjunction/interjection/pronoun/preposition/article"?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111444/discussion-on-question-by-rivers-mcforge-such-as-a-part-of-speech-and-similar).